# What scriptures mention the "Vaikuntha-Kamalaja" form which is Half Vishnu & Half Lakshmi?

Tags: scripture, vishnu, gods, lakshmi

[image]

We all know "Ardhanarishvara"  form of Shiva & Shakti . Similarly. [**Vaikuntha-Kamalaja**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaikuntha_Kamalaja)  
is depicted as   **Vishnu-Lakshmi** ,half male and half female, split down the middle. The right half is the male Vishnu, illustrating his traditional attributes. The icon symbolises the oneness or non-duality of male and female principles of the universe.

My question is-

**1) In which texts , we find mentioning of this composite form of Shri Vishnu and Shree Lakshmi.** , (Preferably mentioning of one or two verses or passages related to this) from original scripture.

Image taken from [This](http://www.baijnathtemple.com/sculpture1.htm) site.

Answer (score 5):

The half-Narayana half-Lakshmi form is referred in the renowned Tantrik compendium named  [**Sharadatilaka**](https://archive.org/details/SharadaTilakaTantramISudhakarMalaviya/page/n451/mode/2up)  composed by Lakshmana Desikendra as the presiding deity of the Keshavâdi Mâtrikânyâsa which is employed while worshipping with Vaishnava mantras. The iconography as stated in Sharadatilaka is :-

> हस्तैर्बिभ्रत् सरसिजगदाशङ्ख चक्राणि विद्यां पद्मादर्शौ कनककलशं
> मेघविद्युद्विलासम् । वामो तुङ्गंस्तनमविरलाकल्पमाश्लेषलोभादेकीभूतं
> वपुरवतु वः पुण्डरीकाक्षलक्ष्म्योः ।।

> Transliteration : May the form
> of Pundarikâksha & Lakshmi, who have united in one body out of
> affection, whose fleshy left breast appears like thunder in midst of
> clouds, bearing lotus, mace, conchshell, discus, book, lotus, mirror &
> pot of gold in their arms, protect us.(Sharadatilaka:6:45)

Comment: What a fabulous find! It would be great if you could also share a link to the scripture if possible.

Comment: Here are the links for part 1(https://archive.org/details/SharadaTilakaTantramISudhakarMalaviya/mode/2up ) & part 2 (https://archive.org/details/SharadaTilakaTantramIISudhakarMalaviya/mode/2up) of the book.

Comment: Wow could you add the link to the answer instead? The iconography as stated in the [Sharadatilaka](paste link here) is: hastair..... also for quoting the relevant part you can use >paste text here.

Comment: Thanks  for answer +1 and accept - Excellent find.Do update the answer with the link.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions & edits. Actually I am quite new in this platform, so it will take some time for me to be familiarised with this site.

Answer (score 1):

Ardhaharilakshmi is worshiped in some of the Vishnu temples who follow agamic (tantric) procedures. During the final rituals of the day i.e after shayana aarati, they worship Ardhaharilakshmi. Some of the temples which follow this are Badrinath, Kedarnath, Jagan nath and few others in Kerela. A scripture named Vamadeva Kalpa written by Gautama Vamadeva has the protocol for this procedure. This is followed in [Jagannath temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagannath_Temple,_Puri) in Puri. 
Source: from a friend.

Comment: We must cite authentic scriptures only. This rule is strictly followed to maintain quality. Please see [What kind of references are valid in answers? Are modern works allowed?](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/596/3500). Also, OPs main question is about scriptures which talk about "Vaikunta Kamalaja" form. If you have any queries, ask them on [Hinduism Meta](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: When query is non vedic then how come one cite vedic references ?
If the subject itself pertains to non-authentic topics then answers will also pertain to that only. 

"""Also, OPs main question is about scriptures which talk about "Vaikunta Kamalaja" form. """

for the same I have quoted "Vamadeva Kalpam" which is followed in Puri temple. how can you find vedic references for agamic or pauranic topics?
if the question is related to a particular form then temple worship of that form is not a bad reference.

Answer (score 1):

There are mentions of a few Composite Forms  = half masculine & half feminine depiction = of Sriman LakshmiNarayan bhagvaan ji in the core vaishanava scriptures like the Pancharatas scriptures.

For example = the Shri Paadma Samhita describes the murti (icon or idol) of one such composite form known as **Abhinna LakshmiNarayan**.

It is found in Paadma Samhita -> KriyaaPaad Adhyay - > Chapter 18

> Verse 52 - Verse 53 =
>
> **अभिन्नालक्ष्मिनारायणमूर्तिः**
>
> वपुषो दक्षिणे भागे विष्णुर्वामे सरोरुहा 
> पीनस्तनतटो वामश्श्री वत्साङ्कस्तथेतरः
> वामो हेमनिभश्श्यामो दक्षिणो भाग इष्यते
> आसीनं वा शयानं वा गरुडारूढमेव वा
>
> On the right side of the body of the icon of the Abhinna LakshmiNarayan Murti, there is Vishnu, and on the left, there is Lakshmi (Saroruhaa). The right side symbolic of Vishnu's chest is marked with the Srivatsa symbol, and the left side of the icon is representative of Lakshmi's [vaksha-sthala](https://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/scans/MWScan/2020/web/webtc/indexcaller.php) . The icon is dark complexioned on its right side (Vishnu's complexion) and the left side is golden complexion (Lakshmi's complexion). The icon may be depicted as either seated, or lying down, or mounted on the Garuda.

References for the Paadma pancharatra Samhita is = https://archive.org/details/PadmaSamhitaSeethaPadmanabhanSampathR.N.Vol1/Padma%20Samhita%20%20Seetha%20Padmanabhan%20Sampath%20R.N.%20Vol%201/page/n171/mode/1up