# Are there any other deities similar to Ardhanarishvara?

Tags: gods, body, gender, deity

[Ardhanarishvara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ardhanarishvara) is a form of Shiva/Parvati who is (simply put) physically half-man and half-woman. Are there any other similar *deities*? (Not mortals.)

(Doesn't necessarily have to be a synthesis of two consorts.)

Comment: There is a form of Vishnu similar to Ardhanarishvara with the left half being that of Lakshmi. See this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16016/what-scriptures-mention-the-vaikuntha-kamalaja-form-which-is-half-vishnu-hal/44436#44436

Comment: @অনু - that's helpful. Feel free to make it into an answer.